# Incorrect result when using v.net.distance on grass76

Tags: grass-gis, network, shortest-path

As shown in the image below I need to connect the points in yellow to the respective nearest point in brown via the shortest path on the road network in blue.

[image: Incorrect result when using v.net.distance]

I decided to use `v.net.distance` on GRASS GIS 7.6 for this purpose as [the documentation for it](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass76/manuals/v.net.distance.html) describes exactly what I need to achieve. However, as visible in the image, the path that was generated (in red) takes a longer route instead of the more obvious shortest path as it is supposed to. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

The commands I used are as follows.

```
v.net roads points=bs op=connect thresh=10000 output=net1
v.net net1 points=end op=connect thresh=1000 output=net2 arc_layer=1 node_layer=3
v.net.distance input=net2 output=network flayer=2 to_layer=3
```

Comment: I suspect that grass thinks it can only go along that line in one direction

Comment: @IanTurton any reason as to why that might happen and what I can do about it?

Comment: I've never used v.net but I'd look for reverse costs in the documentation

Comment: Please also verify that the network is really with all edges connected. `v.net` is the tool to use for network maintenance: https://grass.osgeo.org/grass78/manuals/v.net.html